# How to make the position sticky to the screen

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am making a horizontal website which has a sticky top nav with a side bar which displays the name of page user is viewing. I want to make the side bar stick to the screen when the user reaches the desired page.
Help would be much appreciated.

`link to the pen`

https://codepen.io/vishal2801/pen/ExZJOPK

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Images alone is rarely helpful, please include all relevant code (html, css) and use the snippet `<>` tool

Answer (score 0):

Give your side bar class the following css:

```
<div class="sidebar">
    Content here
</div>

<style>
.sidebar {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1020;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I have tried it but it doesn't really work because I want the bar to stick when user scrolls to  the page

Answer (score -1):

change in css{position: fixed}
For more info, https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: This is not a correct answer, the content will stay in one place and won't be sticky.